# iOS App Thinning - How to implement it depending on screen size?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-thinning

Per default Apple only seems to allow @3x, @2x and @1x as suffixes for images and app thinning.

@3x resources seem to be reserved for iPhone 6/7 Plus, even though their screen resolution is smaller than the resolution of the largest iPad Pro - which seems to use @2x.

Is there any way to specifically have 5 different folders with data and use one folder per actual device resolution that is out there? Those folders would be for example (and any new or in-between resolution would use the closest folder and scale):

- 568p
- 1136p
- 1334p
- 2048p
- 2732p

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Assets in your Xcode project you can click on the + and add a new image set. There you can right click and add iPhone and iPad individually.

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, that's quite interesting actually. So 1x iPad is probably iPad 2 then and 2x iPad is iPad 7'', iPad 10'' and iPad 12'' with Retina displays? Do you know if it's possible to do it more fine grained than that?

Comment: This not depends on the x1,2,3 because, this is not connected to the sizes of the different devices. If you want pixel perfect (for example backgroundImages) then you have to code that and change the image for the width and height of the device itself.

Comment: for example in the 1x screen: to show 50px the image should be 50px. In the 2x screen: to show 50px you need a 100px image, because the 2x screens have two times more pixels in the same space. To have a nice 50px result on a 3x screen you need a 150px image because there a three times more pixels in the same space compared to the x1 devices

Comment: Thanks, I got that - but that was not the actual question ;) For more info, I'm making a game with Open GL so all the 1x, 2x stuff of iOS does not matter for me. I'm dealing raw resources and I would like to split files as fine grained as possible.

Comment: Ok, to answer your question regarding app thinning - you can't https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html